# Is it possible to evolve an awakened monster using non-awakened monsters?

Tags: summoners-war

Let's take this example:

I have a 5 star awakened monster.

Can I use 5, 5 star non-awakened monsters to evolve my 5 star awakened monster to a 6 star awakened?

I don't want to work on awakening my monsters if it's going to keep me from further evolving them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have placed this in comments but not enough rep

Yes you can use 5, 5Star monsters to evolve an awoken max lv 5 star monster, you can also use awoken monsters to upgrade non-awoken monsters (I know this from experience as I am playing the game daily for some time now)

Hope this helps, anything you dont understand just let me know

Comment: Alright cool, so there is basically no reason NOT to awaken a monster right?

Comment: If you are going to use them for fights then yea awaken them, they get a decent stat buff and some get addition skills/passive, if you are going to use them  upgrade food for other monsters, dont bother, awoken/non-awoken provide the same experice when used for food for other monsters

Comment: On a side note, when you get rainbowmons use them for evolving, they do give good experince as food but experice is easy to get from dungons/story missions (find a boss you can auto play and just let your monsters do the work)